# form onSubmit return false doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onsubmit

My return false statement doens't work in Chrome when I want to check the user input through javasript. It fires the action tag even when I return false. Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function testInput(){
    if(document.getElementById("input1").value == ""){
      alert('error');
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

The HTML

```
<form action="exec.php" method="post" onSubmit="return testInput()">
<input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" />
<input type="submit" value="Exec" />
</form>
```

Comment: it is working perfectly in g chrome

Comment: Yes the alert displays and the code works in IE and FF but not in Chrome

Comment: These issues tend to arise when a JavaScript error has occurred and the browser just stops evaluating more code.

Comment: Yes, but the strange thing is that it's work in IE and FF so I think there is nog JS error...

Comment: if anyone of you have downvoted my answer then see there that there was no need to downvote

Comment: @Jack, thank you so much, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late but this reply may help somebody in the future. I encountered the same issue today. After reading Jack's comment I inserted a try/catch block in my check function. This allowed me to prevent execution to stop (returns false even if the code crashes) and to print the error in the Chrome console panel. You can try the same like so :

```
function testInput(){
    try {
        if (document.getElementById("input1").value == "") {
            alert('error');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }   
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is not blank spaces in the input field.

Try something like this     if(document.getElementById("input1").value.**trim()** == "")

Please note that tirm will not work fine in IE. Use this work around if needed http://goo.gl/L802W

Comment: That is weird. 

Few questions
1) What is the chorme version
2) Is it working fine in IE and FF ?

Its seems you are not alone, check this http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Z3MD5Od3oQM