# Calling function issues

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have a couple of javascript functions in my form and i have been trying to call them to no avail, seems like the first function in the list validates just fine but after you enter the correct data for that function to be true it seems to just submit the form without validating the next functions, Here is my code :

```
<form name= "rego" action="submit.htm" onsubmit="return validateText() && validateCheckBoxes(this) && validateRadioButton() && validateEmail() && populateInstitution();" method="POST">
```

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Thats called short circuiting. Youll have to run each function and store each result in variables. Then you can use your comparison on the results

Comment: Try `return (everything here)`. From the look of your code, once the first function returns `true`, it should run the next function. And for code quality sake, don't use inline scripts.

Comment: so put all the individual calls together in brackets?

Comment: Short-circuiting shouldn't be a problem here. It should stop when one of the functions fails, but he says it's stopping when the first function succeeds.

Comment: Show the definition of `validateText()`. I suspect it's not returning `true` as it should.

Comment: I suspect there is an error in your JS code, and *return false* is not executed. The then behavior is browser dependent. See [the first answer of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877135/form-onsubmit-return-false-doesnt-work-in-chrome). The solution there was to add a `try catch` to return *false* in all case (the best would be to fix your code).

Answer (score 0):

That is because of short-circuit evaluation. When evaulating `A && B && C`, after knowing `A` is `false` the result can be determined to `false` and the evaluation is stopped. Similar thing happens when evaluating `A || B || C` while `A` is `true`.

You may want to ensure that your `validateText()` and other functions return `true` when the text is valid instead of having no return statement.

Comment: Is there a specific article or something along those lines where i could learn how to fix this?

Comment: @daniel Please read the Wikipedia on [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: This is not SCE and quite the opposite symptom: the form *is* submitted like if it *was* validated, like all functions were returning true - but operators are `&&`, not `||`!